# Пул задач блокирующая очередь

Tags: java, многопоточность

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
public class ThreadPool {
    private final List<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<>();
    private final Queue<Runnable> tasks = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(); //вообще это блокирующая очередь
    ThreadPool(int size) {                 //инициализация пула
        System.out.println(size + " ядер" + " создаю столько же нитий");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            this.threads.add(new ThreadList(this.tasks, "поток № " + i));
        }
    }
    //добавляем таски
    public void work(Runnable job) {
        tasks.offer(job);
    }
    //из этих тредов будет состоять линкедлист
    private static class ThreadList extends Thread {
        private final Queue<Runnable> task;
        Thread t;

        ThreadList(Queue<Runnable> queou, String name) {
            t = this;
            t.setName(name);
            System.out.println("создаю поток " + name);
            this.task = queou;
            start();                                                // поток сразу стартует
            try {
                join();                                               //главный поток будет ждать пока этот не завершится
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Runnable r = task.poll(); //я думал блокирующая очередь и здесь должно сработать wait(); и поток бы освободил монитор для следующего потока и ждал своей очереди
            new Thread(r).start();
        }
    }
}
```

как мне сделать чтобы Треды запущенные ждали? зачем такая блокирующая очередь у которой wait отсутствует чем она блокирующая? вообще правильно ли я делаю пул потоков?

пытался сделать так

```
@Override
        public void run() {         
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                while (task.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Жду");
                    try {
                        task.wait();    //вот тут запара какая то я вроде хочу чтоб очередь ждала если она пустая а у меня ошибки в миониторе идут
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                    Thread stTask = new Thread(task.poll()); // получается что мы каждый поток разбили ещё на нити и создавали
                    stTask.start();
                    System.out.println(stTask.getName());
                    try {
                        stTask.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
            }
        }
```

в мониторе ошибки посыпались

```
2 ядер создаю столько же нитий
создаю поток поток № 0
Жду
Exception in thread "поток № 0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:328)
    at ru.job4j.pool.ThreadPool$ThreadList.run(ThreadPool.java:57)
создаю поток поток № 1
Жду
Exception in thread "поток № 1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:328)
    at ru.job4j.pool.ThreadPool$ThreadList.run(ThreadPool.java:57)
```

Comment: Кстати, ваш лог говорит, что ошибка из-за того, что wait() вызывается не в синхронизированном блоке. // task.wait();  добавьте synchronized

Answer (score 1):

Блокирующая очередь от обычной отличается наличием операции добавления, с блокировкой текущего потока, если очередь заполнена, и операцией извлечения с блокировкой текущего потока, если очередь пуста.

Пример использования - система публикатор - подписчик.

Зы. Извините что только текстом, пишу с телефона.

Comment: это я понимаю типо если мы пытаемся прочитать из блокирующей очереди то будем ждать пока туда задача не поступит, вот только поток вообще не ждёт почему?

Answer (score 1):

> `Runnable r = task.poll(); //я думал блокирующая очередь и здесь должно сработать wait(); и поток бы освободил монитор для следующего потока и ждал своей очереди`
>
> как мне сделать чтобы Треды запущенные ждали? зачем такая блокирующая очередь у которой wait отсутствует чем она блокирующая?

Согласно документации метод poll() не ждет элементы, а возвращает null:

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.

Для ожидания доступности элементов вам нужно использовать методы

```
poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
```

или

```
take()
```

Используйте интерфейс `BlockingQueue` вместо `Queue`

Comment: а как сделать чтобы онсоной поток дождался пока этот не завершит свою работу? пробывал ставить join  основной поток виснет, и не хочет добавлять в блокирующую очередь задачи       
  @Override
        public void run() {
            Runnable r = null;
            try {
               r = task.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            Thread k = new Thread(r);
            k.start();
             }